# How to pass an HTML array from one form to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I am trying to pass an HTML element, which is an array, to another form. Not so difficult, I'd say, but I tried almost all possible combinations, and it doesn't work.

I have a form where I have this SELECT element:

```
<select name="preselectedCountries[]" size="9" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
```

And I have another form:

```
<form method="post" name="formGeneric" action="">
  <input type='hidden' name='preselectedCountries[]' value='' />
```

Now, I'd like to hand over the selection from the first form to the second. Tried it in various forms like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.formGeneric.preselectedCountries =
document.formIndex.preselectedCountries;"
```

Or

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.formGeneric.preselectedCountries[] = 
document.formIndex.preselectedCountries[];"
```

and others... but in vain.

I have searched around quite a bit, but did not find the solution. Can anyone give me a tip?! I would very much appreciate that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Id start by dropping the [] from your element names as that will only serve to confuse things.

Then the line of javascript you need is

```
var selectObject = document.getElementsByName('preselectedCountries')[0];
var selectedArray = [];

for (var i=0; i < selectObject.options.length; i++)
{
 if(selectObject.options[i].selected)
 {
  selectedArray.push(selectObject.options[i].value);
 }
}
```

assuming your hidden form is always after your visible form in the DOM tree, this should give you an array with the selected values in your select list. What you then do with this array is up to you. You can `ToString()` it and attach it as the value of your hidden input field or try and attach the array directly.

Comment: Thanks Simon. But it seems to me that this way only the first element in the array is being passed, not all selected elements.

Comment: What array? You said you wanted the selected value from the drop down list to populate an element in your hidden form.

Comment: Ahem, no, as the tile indicates "How to pass an HTML array from one form to another" it's about an array (multi-select), not a single value.